# Move right to next cell in Excel using vb.net

Tags: vb.net, excel, visual-studio

I need to name my headers according to the items I have in a combo box. I'm basically taking the items from a combo box and adding them to the end of an existing header row in a excel sheet, so starting at the first empty cell in the headers row. However, I can't seem to move to the next cell to the right which would be the next header/column name. Here is my code thus far:

```
For i = 0 To ComboBox1.Items.Count - 1
    Dim s As String
    s = Convert.ToString(ComboBox1.Items(i))
    xlWorkSheet.Range(columnName & "1").Value = s
Next i
```

ColumnName is the next blank header in that row, Column "L", so from there i would like to populate that cell then move to the right to the next cell.

Comment: Try using cells instead, something like: `xlWorkSheet.Cells(1,(i+1)).Value = s`. I don't see where you are incrementing the columnName variable anywhere.

Comment: I guess that's where my issue is. I can find the next empty cell in the header row (columnName) but I can't figure out how to increment to the next cell to the right.

Comment: Something like this should return the last column `LastCol = xlWorkSheet.Cells(1, xlWorkSheet.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column`. Increment that in your for loop to add new headers at the end of your sheet.

Comment: I am already doing that, that's what columnName is, its the last column. I just don't know how to increment that value.

Comment: What I think is happening is that line is becoming `xlWorkSheet.Range(1).Value`, and `1` isn't a range.

Comment: Still unable to increment to the next cell... columnName = "L" how do i get it to increment for every item in my combo box??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others have suggested, you can use `Cells()` to help iterate easier. Note that the user/macro needs the column *number*, not *letter*:

Edit: How's this instead:

```
Dim s   As String
Dim myCol As Long
For i = 0 To ComboBox1.Items.Count - 1
    myCol = Range(columnName & 1).Column
    s = Convert.ToString(ComboBox1.Items(i))
    xlWorksheet.Cells(1, myCol + i).Value = s
Next i
```

Comment: Range in your function isn't working "isnt accessible in this context because it is a friend"

Comment: @Chrisetiquette - ...what? It's throwing an error at `changeToNumber = Range(...`??  Edit: Ah, I made this in VBA, you may need to tweak for VB.net. sorry!

Comment: your edit just changes the next column to the last item in the combo box

Comment: @Chrisetiquette how about now, I forgot to add the `i`

Answer (score 0):

Loops are so yesterday :]
You can set all headers at once with something like:

```
Dim headers = ComboBox1.Items.Cast(Of Object).ToArray
xlWorkSheet.Range("A1").Resize(1, headers.Length).Value2 = headers
```

Also, when you get acceptable answer you should check the green check next to it https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score 0):

- you can create a method that will get parameter of the column number
  to start, use counter to point the column index.
- if headers are not in row 1 so add another parameter of row    and
  replace  `xlWorksheet.Cells(1, counter)` with
  `xlWorksheet.Cells(yourNewParameter, counter)`.
- use `short` or `integer` data type not `Long`.
- you dont need to create a variable for  `xlWorksheet.Cells(1,
  counter)`
        make your code shorter.

code:

```
Private Sub AddHeaders(ByVal columnNumberToStart As Short)
    Dim counter As Short = columnNumberToStart
    For i = 0 To ComboBox1.Items.Count - 1
        xlWorksheet.Cells(1, counter) = ComboBox1.Items(i).ToString()
        counter += 1
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what finally worked for me

```
Dim headers = ComboBox1.Items.Cast(Of Object).ToArray
        xlWorkSheet.Range(columnName & "1").Resize(1, headers.Length).Value2 = headers
```

Answer (score 0):

This also worked:

```
  For i = 0 To ComboBox1.Items.Count - 1
            Dim s As String
            myCol = xlWorkSheet.Range(columnName & 1).Column
            s = Convert.ToString(ComboBox1.Items(i))
            xlWorkSheet.Cells(1, myCol + i).Value = s
        Next i
```